# Trie data structures - Java

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

Is there any library or documentation/link which gives more information of implementing Trie data structure in java?

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could read up on [Java Trie](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706) or look at [trie](https://github.com/brianfromoregon/trie).

Answer (score 7):

There's a java implementation in [Robert Sedgewick's book on algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X). It's very basic, i.e., no compression and a very simple interface, but I found it instructive to understand how tries work.

I also recently found a [library](https://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees/) that includes a memory efficient concurrent implementation of tries which looks very promising. It even includes a LCS solver using tries.

There is also the [Lucene implementation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-stempel/org/egothor/stemmer/Trie.html) that's used in production applications.

Answer (score 4):

Another implementation, I believe from Limewire developers originally: https://github.com/rkapsi/patricia-trie