# Data structure used for search suggestions

Tags: java, algorithm, search, autocomplete, full-text-search

What is the data structure used for search suggestions like Google Suggest. Does it all depend on the application? Would be helpful someone give me a link to good reference!

Answer (score 4):

Consider a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Here's a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806788/trie-data-structures-java) about good implementations. This [book](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~hilfingr/cs61b/f2002/public_html/data-structures.pdf) will give more in-depth coverage.

But this approach assumes that what has already been typed is spelled correctly. If that is not a reasonable assumption, you will need to do something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for "**autocomplete**".

Here's a [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html) for a jQuery plugin that does autocomplete.

Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21u8C81MLQI) for how it's done.

And [here's](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm) really a lot of information about a detailed version.