# Filtering out strings from a HashSet (or other collection)

Tags: java, string

I am reading the contents of a txt file into a `HashSet`. The file contains almost every word in the English language, and each word becomes a String in the `HashSet`.

In my app, characters are being added to a String. I want to check whether this String is, or can become equal to, any of the Strings in the `HashSet`. That is, say the `HashSet` contains only the String *apple*. I have a String *appl*, and now I want to filter out the `HashSet` until it becomes a set with only Strings that start with *appl* (in this case a set with only *apple*).

I can iterate over the entire `HashSet` and use the `startsWith(String)` method, as I build a new filtered `HashSet`. But my initial `HashSet` is very big, so my question is: Is there a more efficient way to do this (perhaps using a different type of Collection?)

Some code of how I would do it right now:

```
private HashSet<String> filter(String partOfWord){
    HashSet<String> filteredSet = new HashSet<>();

    for (String word : dictionary) { // dictionary is the full HashSet
        if (word.startsWith(partOfWord)) {
            filteredSet.add(word);
        }
    }
    return filteredSet;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at a Trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). There's nothing built-in in Java, but there are plenty of open source implementations.

Comment: There are predefined libraries which you can use to solve this problem using Trie datastructures. For reference, use the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806788/trie-data-structures-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is the ultimate weapon of doom for this task, but you can get good efficiency out of a `TreeSet`:

```
private TreeSet<String> dictionary;

private TreeSet<String> filter(String partOfWord) {
    return (TreeSet<String>)dictionary.subSet(partOfWord, partOfWord + "zzz");
}
```

Everything that start with "appl" is also *between* "appl" (inclusive if it's a word itself) and "applzzz" (no English word has 3 consecutive "z"'s in it), which is lexicographically greater than all words that start with "appl". The time complexity of the call to `subset()` is `O(log n)` to find the start of the subset and `O(m)` (m = number returned) for the range, which is pretty good.

Note that if you are able to reuse the returned set as your new dictionary as your word grows, you will have much more efficient code overall.

The cast to `TreeSet<String>` is needed because `subSet()` is a method of the `SortedSet` interface and returns a `SortedSet`, but it's [*covariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) because the [`TreeSet` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet-E-E-) returns a *view* (another efficiency benefit), which is of course another `TreeSet`.

For improved efficiency, but uglier code, you could use a sorted `String[]` and `Arrays.binarySearch()`, then once you located your hit, you could quickly iterate along the array collection your hits.

Note that both the `TreeSet` and sorted array have `O(log n)` look-up time, whereas a `HashSet` (although unsuitable for the task) is `O(1)` look up time.

Comment: If `startsWith` were to be a TreeSet as well, I could call this code again on the filtered sets, yes?

Comment: @Chronicle `startsWith()` is a `String` method - `TreeSet` doesn't have relevance to it.

Comment: I meant in your code, you created a new `Set<String>` called `startsWith`.

Comment: @Chronicle ahh!. See edit. But unless you need to do something similar, any set would do. Although as your word length grows, you could limit your dictionary to the last filtered set returned, which would be very efficient :)

Comment: That's the idea! Excellent answer. By the way, you forgot to replace the variable `stem` in your code with `partOfWord` after your edits.

Comment: @Chronicle OK - thx. I would write two versions - one like the code posted, and another where you pass in the dictionary last returned. Also, note an even *better* version now!!!

Comment: +1, by the way, subset() returned a SortedSet not a TreeSet. Maybe I am missing something, but for the array based solution, if hit is not in the array, will it still work?

Comment: @dragon66 cast added to code. Note also discussion of why cast is needed and safe.

Comment: @Bohemian: thanks. Given the implementation detail of the TreeSet subset(), it is a safe cast to TreeSet but say it's covariant, I am a little bit suspicious unless you don't need the cast.