# What data structure I should use for my dictionary?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, data-structures

I would like to create a dictionary containing about 10 000 word pairs in Java, but I don't know what data structure I should use. If I have a word in my dictionary, for example `because`, I would like to the program find it if I search for only `bec`. If I have a phrase like `the end` I would like to find it if I search for `th` or `en`.

I tried `ArrayList`, but search is pretty slow. I don't want to use classes that implement the `Map` interface because they can only store one value for one key, so I can't search as described above.

This answer list some data structures for dictionaries, but I don't think they are the best for me: [Best data structure for implementing a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017808/best-data-structure-for-dictionary-implementation)

Comment: You can store one value per key in a `Map`, but nothing prevents you from having that value as a `Set` or `List`, or even another `Map`...

Comment: Why dont you use a sql database? Then you could use the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you are searching for is a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).**

As the java framework does not seem to have an implementation of one, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806788/trie-data-structures-java) for possible libraries and solutions:

explanations and basic java implementation in [Robert Sedgewick's book "Algorithms"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X)

explanations and basic java implementation on [Patel's blog](http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2015/07/trie-datastructure-explanation-and-applications.html)

explanations and basic java implementation on [an oracle thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706)

java library ["Concurrent Radix and Suffix Trees for Java"](https://github.com/npgall/concurrent-trees) on GitHub

java library ["Practical Algorithm to Retrieve Information Coded in Alphanumeric (PATRICIA)"](https://github.com/rkapsi/patricia-trie) on GitHub

[a java library](https://github.com/brianfromoregon/trie/tree/master/src/main/java/net/bcharris/trie) by brianfromoregon on GitHub

Comment: Could you add a summary of the link to the answer? Links have a tendency to die after a while.

Comment: It's fine if I only store words. But if I store for example "the end", a trie will only list "the end" (and it's meaning) if I type "t", "th" or "the". But I want to list it if I type "e", "en" or "end". So I want to list phrases if any of it's words starts with the letters I typed to the search area.

Comment: @racz16 I don't think there's a structure for optimized ``String#contains`` checks, but depending on the phrase length you could check for its substrings, e.g. "the end", "he end", "e end", " end", "end", "nd", "d", "".

Comment: Finally, I implemented a trie, and it works fine, it's pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NavigableSet which allows you to do partial lookups.

```
NavigableSet<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
words.add("tee");
words.add("the");
words.add("there");
words.add("tidy");

String th = words.higher("th");
System.out.println("th ... "+th);
```

prints

```
th ... the
```

If you want multiple words you can do

```
NavigableSet<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
words.add("tee");
words.add("the");
words.add("their");
words.add("there");
words.add("tidy");

String start = "th";
for (String w : subSet(start, start + '\uffff')) {
    System.out.println(start + " ... " + w);
}
```

which prints

```
th ... the
th ... their
th ... there
```

You can use a separate map to look up phrases by word.

Note: This would be between 1000x and 10000x faster than using an SQL database.

Comment: I don't understand perfectly what you said, can you explain it a bit more detailed? It only stores a word, not a word with it's meaning, and if I type "th" I want to list all words starts with "th", so not only "the", but also "there"  should be listed.

Comment: @racz16 I have updated my answer to include multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use simple array
2. Sort the array
3. Search with binary search

This is the fastest solution if you fill the dictionary once and then do only searches.

Words that begin with same letters would be stacked together next to each other.

Additional tree indexes are only useful if the data is large enough.